# Django render_to_string adding '\n' to XML template

Tags: python, xml, django, django-templates

I am trying to render a xml template to a string in the view to make a soap request to a web service. When I do `loader.render_to_string('app/services/soap/item_update.xml', context, None)`, the string I get have break lines (\n) where I have pressed enter. Below is an example.

Ex XML Code:

```
<name>Das</name>
<city>Col</city>
```

Corresponding string:

```
'<name>Das</name>\n    <city>Col</city>'
```

The type of the rendered response is `<class 'django.utils.safestring.SafeText'>`

Is there a way to render the string without the line breaks, since making a Soap request with it sends a 400 response?

Comment: Yes, that is a line break. What is wrong that needs fixing?

Comment: When I make a Soap request with the line break in it, it sends a 400 response.

Comment: You don't have XML. The root tag is missing.

Comment: "When I make a Soap request with the line break in it, it sends a 400 response" unless you have a completely broken soap implementation that's very very very unlikely

Comment: I checked the implementation and it is fine. When I make the entire xml file one line it works.

Comment: newlines __outside__ tags are not significant, so either your problem is elsewhere or your soap service is utterly broken.

Comment: FWIW note that you can generate XML with dedicated tools like ` elementtree` which will make sure your XML is at least well-formed. Oh, and yes: have you tried parsing your template-generated XML with a XML parser ? It might detect if/where your XML is broken.

Comment: Thanks bruno, turns out there was a stray character. Weird it worked before when I made the content one line.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, you could just replace the newline characters.

```
xml_as_string = loader.render_to_string('app/services/soap/item_update.xml', context, None)
xml_as_string = xml_as_string.replace("\n", "")
```

*Note* this will remove newlines from within your tags as well.

Line breaks and whitespace outside of tags really shouldn't be causing an issue.
In addition XML should have only one root node other than the encoding tag. See section 2.1 [of the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/), the relevant part being...

> There is exactly one element, called the root, or document element, no part of which appears in the content of any other element.

Comment: you are aware that your "solution" will remove __all__ newline characters - not only those between tags -, are you ?

Comment: Great point, I missed that, must have just been paying attention to the example given and solved for that rather than the more general case.